# Synchronized child property in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Question is implementation pattern for the following.

A container UI has child UIs. For example, the container has a property of `ObservableCollection<ChildItemViewModel>` that is applied to `<ChildItem DataContext="{Binding}" />` in XAML template.

I want a property of `ChildItemViewModel` synchronized among hosted `ChildItem`s. As setting/unsetting `PropertyChanged` event seems messy, binding is preferable. An idea is that the parent UI has a dependency property bound in two-way to a corresponding dependency property (also bound to a property of the `ChildItemViewModel`) of every child UI in the template, which still seems redundant to prepare such dependency properties.

May I have your **declarative** and MVVM-natural way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are talking about is setting a property on the parent view model from it's child view model the way I usually do it is as follows:

- Add a constructor to the child view model that takes the parent view
  model as a parameter and assign that to a field in the child view
  model.
- Add a method to the parent view model to change the desired
  property.
- Call method from child property (using the 'parent' field).

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: How do you sync the value among children? It becomes messy after all in your way...

Comment: If your parent view model has multiple children that need syncronising then the two options are either to create a global reference to the property that needs to be synced, or (my prefered method) is to check for which child view models need syncing at the point at which you update the parent property.

Comment: Actually, if all view models that need to be synced are created from the same parent you can use a combination of both methods and probably get the best result.

What you can do is rather than have the child view models store a local version of the property they could all reference a common property on the parent view model.

That way when the parent view model is updated all child view models will receive the update.

Comment: As you recommend reference in property may make sense and intrinsic. Thank you for providing many possible ways.